# Unexploded Cows placing into another player's herd

Tags: unexploded-cow

So the rules state that you can place on another player's herd and that it must be placed on either end of the herd. However it doesn't not state who decides which end it goes on. The person playing the card or the owner of the herd.

We played with a decision of the person playing the card would get to choose, but we didn't find it clear enough to make a ruling.

Comment: The Deluxe Edition does have a rule for this. Not sure about the original version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules I found [here](http://www.cheapass.com/sites/default/files/UXCRulesPDF.pdf) state:

> On your turn, you may rearrange your field as much as you want.
>   However, you can not rearrange someone else’s field, **so when you
>   play a cow on someone, it must go at either end of the line (your
>   choice**).

So, whoever plays a cow on someone else's herd, they decide on which end it goes.

Comment: It's worth adding that players cannot rearrange their herds until their turn. So if the cow is placed on an unfavorable end, they are stuck there until that player's turn.